# GPG server hides search results?

Tags: gnupg

I'm new with gpg, I've tried `--search-keys: "Bitcoin"` - nothing found,

```
C:\Users\bdimych>gpg2 --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --batch --search-keys "Bitcoin"
gpg: searching for "Bitcoin" from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: key "Bitcoin" not found on keyserver
```

then `--search-keys "Bitcoin Core"` - found several entries.

```
C:\Users\bdimych>gpg2 --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --batch --search-keys "Bitcoin Core"
gpg: searching for "Bitcoin Core" from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
(1)     Wladimir J. van der Laan (Bitcoin Core binary release signing key) <la
          4096 bit RSA key 36C2E964, created: 2015-06-24, expires: 2017-02-13
(2)     A Core Dev <acoredev@bitcoin.org>
          4096 bit RSA key 7855F004, created: 2014-09-13, expires: 2024-09-10
Keys 1-2 of 2 for "Bitcoin Core".  gpg: Sorry, we are in batchmode - can't get input
```

It looks like the server has some filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply hitting the maximum number of allowed keys in an answer.  For example searching my username:

```
$ gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --batch --search-keys "grochmal"
gpg: data source: http://mira.cbaines.net:11371
(1) Michal Grochmal <REDACTED>
    Michal Grochmal <REDACTED>
    Michal Grochmal <REDACTED>
      2048 bit RSA key 040E2771C840C4F6, created: 2014-08-21
Keys 1-1 of 1 for "grochmal".  gpg: Sorry, we are in batchmode - can't get input
```

But searching a common name would give a huge amount of keys, and the server will refuse to answer:

```
$ gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --batch --search-keys "mike"
gpg: error searching keyserver: No data
gpg: keyserver search failed: No data
```

In the Bitcoin case all that the server is telling you is that you exceeded the maximum number of allowed keys with your search for "Bitcoin", and you should try a more specific term (which "Bitcoin Core", or even simply "Bitcoin Co" turns to be).

The maximum number of returned keys that can be returned has been 1000 in the past (on pgp.subkeys.net).  But that is information from 10 years ago, I may be wrong, and the number is probably different now.